# What is the order of execution of setup scripts in a module?

Tags: module, magento-1, installation, setup-script

**1)** Can there be multiple install scripts in the custom module? For example:

- data-install-1.0.0.php
- data-install-1.0.1.php

**2)** Assuming I have the following scripts inside app/code/local/Company/Helloworld/data/helloworld_setup:

- data-install-1.0.0.php
- data-install-1.0.1.php
- data-install-1.0.2.php
- data-install-2.0.0.php
- data-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php
- data-upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php
- data-upgrade-1.0.2-2.0.0.php
- data-upgrade-2.0.0-2.0.1.php

**Questions:**

**2.1)** I already have version 1.0.0 of this module installed in my Magento:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Helloworld>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_Helloworld>
    </modules>
...
</config>
```

What will be the order of execution of these scripts when:

**2.1.a)** I install version 1.0.2

**2.1.b)** I install version 2.0.0

**2.2)** I don't have any version of this module installed yet.
What will be the order of execution of these scripts when:

**2.2.a)** I install version 1.0.0

**2.2.b)** I install version 2.0.0

**2.2.c)** I install version 3.0.0

**3)** I've seen in Magento core modules, the sql install scripts are named in two ways:

- mysql4-install-1.0.0.php
- install-1.0.0.php

When is **mysql4-** required in the script name? When can I remove **mysql4-** from the name? Does it depend on Magento version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes you can have multiple install scripts
2. (a) If you already have 1.0.0 installed and upgrade to 2.0.0 all the scripts that start with `install` will not be executed. So in the example you gave only `data-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php`, `data-upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php` and `data-upgrade-1.0.2-2.0.0.php` will be executed.
   (b) the `mysql4-` prefix was required in versions prior to 1.6 (not including 1.6). From 1.6 and later the scripts should run even if they have or they don't have `mysql4-` prefix.

And an addition to 2a. If you don't have any version of the module installed and you install it directly with version `2.0.0` then only `data-install-2.0.0.php` will be executed.  If you install it at version `3.0.0` again only `data-install-2.0.0.php` will be executed. So when installing a module at a certain version only the install script with a number lower (the closest) or equal to the version is executed.

**[EDIT]**

2.1.a You have 1.0.0 installed and get the 1.0.2 version. Executed scripts:

- data-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php
- data-upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php

2.1.b You have 1.0.0 installed and get the 2.0.0 version. Executed scripts:

- data-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php
- data-upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php
- data-upgrade-1.0.2-2.0.0.php

2.2.a Nothing installed and get version 1.0.0. Executed scripts

- data-install-1.0.0.php

2.2.b Nothing installed and get version 2.0.0. Executed scripts

- data-install-2.0.0.php

2.2.c Nothing installed and get version 3.0.0. Executed scripts

- data-install-2.0.0.php
- data-upgrade-2.0.0-2.0.1.php

You can test this by creating a dummy extension where all the files contain only this:

```
Mage::log(__FILE__, null, 'install-scripts.log', true);
```

Then test your version combinations and look in `var/log/install-scripts.log` to see the order

Comment: Thank you. To be sure I understand everything correctly I edited and extended my example in point 2). I will appreciate if you could edit your answer and include all of these different cases. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @zitix. I edited my answer.