# Why two installer files in core Cms module

Tags: setup-script

I am working with custom module upgrade script. I know Once Magento runs an installer script for a module, it will never run another installer for that module again. I checked core "Cms" module  I found two installer script mysql4-install-0.7.0.php and  install-1.6.0.0.php. why two installer files? which will run or both will run? in which sequence they will run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what version you install the module.
In the CMS case (or any other module in the core) the file `mysql4-install-0.7.0.php` existed in versions prior to 1.6.
If you install Magento 1.5 for example `mysql4-install-0.7.0.php` will be exectuted (and there was no `install-1.6.0.0.php` in 1.5)..

If you install version 1.6 or later the `install-1.6.0.0.php` will be executed.

See this question and answer to understand how install and upgrade scripts are executed: [What is the order of execution of setup scripts in a module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/26313/146)