# Add new field in magento(1.9) customer registration

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, forms

I like to add new field in customer registration and admin customer creation form.

The field name is **license number**. I searched so many links related to my requirement but those do not work in Magento (1.9). Even I found the extension related to this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custome-account-profile-13594.html

When I installed the above extension using key, it shows an error.
Can you please give some idea related to my requirement?

Comment: Also provide what error you are getting in above extension...please send as much details as you can..

Comment: This has been previously answered here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer

Comment: Any help to add license number at checkout page billing and shipping section?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to create a new extension to make it clean.
Let's call the extension `StackExchange_Customer`.
You will need the following files:

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Customer.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Customer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends><Mage_Customer/></depends>
        </StackExchange_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Customer>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <stackexchange_customer>
                <class>StackExchange_Customer_Helper</class>
            </stackexchange_customer>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <stackexchange_customer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>StackExchange_Customer</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </stackexchange_customer_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <stackexchange_customer>
                    <file>stackexchange_customer.xml</file>
                </stackexchange_customer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <StackExchange_Customer>
                    <files>
                        <default>StackExchange_Customer.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </StackExchange_Customer>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/sql/stackexchange_customer_setup/install-1.0.0.php` - the install file. Will add the new attribute.

```
<?php
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'license_number', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'License Number',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'position'  => 120,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'license_number');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/Helper/Data.php` - the module main helper

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Customer_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

This will add your attribute for the customer.
It should work nicely on the backend.
Unfortunately you have to edit the frontend templates manually now because Magento does not have any event or empty block where you can put your fields.
For this you need the following.

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/stackexchange_customer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account_edit>
        <reference name="customer_edit">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>stackexchange_customer/form/edit.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_edit>
    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>stackexchange_customer/register.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

And now the templates.

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/stackexchange_customer/register.phtml` - the registration template.
For this one make a clone of the `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` and just insert this somewhere inside the form. I don't need to post the full file here. Arrange it as you please

```
<li>
    <label for="license_number"><?php echo $this->__('License Number') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="license_number" id="license_number" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getLicenseNumber()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('License Number') ?>" class="input-text" />
    </div>
</li>
```

`/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/stackexchange_customer/form/edit.phtml` For this one clone `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/form/edit.phtml` and insert somewhere inside the form this:

```
<li>
    <label for="license_number"><?php echo $this->__('License Number') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="license_number" id="license_number" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getLicenseNumber()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('License Number') ?>" class="input-text" />
    </div>
</li>
```

You can also create the translation file. Is not mandatory but it's nice to have

`app/locale/en_US/StackExchange_Customer.csv`

```
"License Number","License Number"
```

Clear the cache and you should be set.

Comment: i follow as per you way, but the field not show on the admin crate user page.

Comment: @senthil. You are right. Sorry about that. I pasted the wrong install script. I updated the answer with the correct `app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/sql/stackexchange_customer_setup/install-1.0.0.php` file. Since you already installed the module, the new install script won't run again. To make it run again you need to delete from the table `eav_attribute` the attribute with the code `license_number` and from the table `core_resource` the record with the code `StackExchange_Customer`. Clear the cache and refresh the page. The install script should run again.

Comment: if suppose i will add some other filed in feature means, i just change the  install-1.0.0.php files its enough , or need to do some other changes in module folder.

Comment: @senthil If you plan to add other fields you should clone `install-1.0.0` to `upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1` and do your modifications in the cloned file. Then change the `version` tag in `config.xml` to `1.0.1`. See how upgrade scripts work here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/26313/146

Comment: its only enough to change in confix.xml version tag or need to change in stackexchange_customer.xml version tag also ?

Comment: just `config.xml`

Comment: Hi sir ,you didnt tell us How to set multiple attributes ? I tried for multiple attrs by modifying your code. Still not working . Please explain

Comment: I don't quite understand why we choose from the `persistence` directory.

Comment: Hi, @Marius I created two attributes, username and userimage, on backend both works well but on frontend username get save but userimage doesn't. I have to do some extra work for image uploading?

Comment: @Haris, for uploads, you most probably have to do something extra, but I don't know what.

Comment: How does getLicenseNumber() work? I used a different name for my attribute and it worked creating the attribute in the database but its not saving to the customer attribute

Comment: @Marius Hello, I tried to add attribute and to display it in new customer add form in backend. But this is the error when i click on add new customer button. (i.e. On earlier page, customer grid page)
**There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.**

Eav_attribute table shows my new attribute but this is the error on new customer form page.
Please help.

Comment: It's not working on Checkout page -Register as a guest,value not saved

Comment: @Marius I have a problem with the saving value of this custom attribute, when i create or edit an account he dont save the value, but when i edit it manually in a backoffice and i save, i can get it in front !

Comment: Can any body know if i want to get collection of this license_number then what should i do? @Marius

Comment: @Marius I follow you script and it works fine +1. But I can do `$customer->setData('myfiledname','test');` this in only Events, I tried to update the field value from controller but cannot. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Marius I just want area field from billing and shipping section at the checkout page, help me thanks.

Comment: @Marius is there way to show this field in billing address section on magento 1.9 and shows admin order info address areas