# Is there a way to inject an extra hidden parameter to the customer login/register forms?

Tags: login, forms, register

Is there a way to add an extra parameter to the customer login/register forms with out modifying the design templates directly ?

I have a local module, Is it possible to add the parameter from this module ?

Comment: rewrite the phtml in your module and then you can add a hidden field there.!

Comment: Is that the only way ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in your modules `layout.xml` or `local.xml`, should do the trick, however adding some dynamic value would need some PHP logic.

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields">
            <value>true</value>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Comment: Hi All I want is to call two php functions from Head.phtml. Sorry Wrong comment in wrong place... :)

Comment: So by specifying like this.. The input tag will come in HTML registration page ? Then I can fill it up with some JS code.

Comment: I believe the only approach in this case is: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration