# How to View customer registration information on order -> account infromation block (backend)

Tags: orders, customer, additional-information

According to this example 
[Add new field in magento(1.9) customer registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration)

How can I show the customer License Number on admin panel order view page (account information tab)?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the customer attribute as explained in [Add new field in magento(1.9) customer registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration) you have to add a new attribute on the quote and the order called `customer_licence_number`. (add them as columns to the tables `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_order`). The prefix `customer_` is very important.
Then you have to add in the `config.xml` of you module, under the tags `<config><global><fieldsets>` this:

```
<customer_account>
    <licence_number>
        <to_quote>customer_licence_number</to_quote>
    </licence_number>
</customer_account>
<sales_convert_quote>
    <customer_licence_number>
        <to_order>*</to_order>
    </customer_licence_number>
</sales_convert_quote>
```

this should make magento copy the value of `licence_number` from the customer to the quote and from the quote to the order.
And because the attribute code starts with `customer_` it will be displayed in the order details page right up there with customer name, email, DOB and others.