# Add new field in customer billing and shipping page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom

I used this tutorial: [Add new field in magento(1.9) customer registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration) to add new custom field in magento.

But I want to show custom field in **billing and shipping address**. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok.
Lets Go to your "billing.phtml" file Which is Located at

```
frontend\rwd\default\template\persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

And Paste Following Code If You want to Checkbox Field.

```
<div class="field">
    <input id="p_method_cashondelivery" value="cashondelivery" type="checkbox" name="cod" title="Cash On Delivery" onclick="<?php echo "checked!!!!";?>" class="checkbox" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="p_method_cashondelivery">Cash On Delivery </label>
</div>
```

Same Way You Can Add Custom Field In Shipping Address File.

```
frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
```

Comment: i tested but not worked !

Answer (score 2):

Please place this code too at end line of your installer code after the  " $attribute->save();" function call.

```
$installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('sales_flat_quote_address')} ADD COLUMN `license_number` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL AFTER `fax`;
    ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('sales_flat_order_address')} ADD COLUMN `license_number` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL AFTER `fax`;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```