# Custom field get but dont set the value in customer registration

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I want to know how to solve this issue, I have a problem with the saving value of the custom attribute, i referred to [this tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration) .I had done the same thing as the tutorial thats why I didn't put my code. So when i create or edit an account he dont save the value of this custom attribute, but when i edit it manually in a backend and i save, i can get it in front !

The field that doesn't set value:

```
<li>
   <label for="w_telephone"><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
      <div class="input-box">
         <input type="text" name="w_telephone" id="w_telephone" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getWTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text" />
      </div>
</li>
```

the new one for testing:

```
<li>
   <label for="w_pincode" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Code pin') ?></label>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="w_pincode" id="w_pincode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomer()->getWPincode()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Code pin')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
      </div>
</li>
```

I tried to add a new one for testing, this new one "w_pine" works fine  but not that of before "w_telephone".

Comment: did you add the form field to relevant form

Comment: once print your post request in proper controller and find that your field is in request with value or not

Comment: Update your controller saveAction

Comment: Logout admin and then try

Comment: Look my edit please, yes i have my form field @Mujahidh 
i checked all parameters in navigator and he set the value of telephone field @ Gopal Patel
Why i should update the savAction() ? @ Kothari
the samthing doesnt work @ Supravat

Comment: check your installer script for correct naming.May be you are missing that.Check "w_telephone" the same one is exist there too.

Comment: I recreated another and I changed the name completely`w_phonenumber` but it is still the same problem

Comment: I solved the problem, I had some line commented in my install script thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, i hade some lines commented in my install script

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "w_telephone",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Telephone",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => true


));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "w_telephone");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'w_telephone',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$used_in_forms=array();
//these lines start
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
//these lines end
$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
    ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
    ->setData("is_system", 0)
    ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
    ->setData("is_visible", 1)
    ->setData("sort_order", 100)
;
$attribute->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```