# How to add Custom Field to Billing Customer Address

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, customer-attribute, registration

I want to add a custom filed on the Billing Customer Address and i want this filed to appears on the registration page too.

Does anyone know what steps i need to follow to do this?
The only thing I found is this link: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/

but this post is from 2011 and i don't know if it will work, because i use **magento 1.9.2.4**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have to add the field in the two templates:

Billing : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

Register: `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/form/register.phtml`

2) Then you add the field in admin panel.

Maybe this one do your need https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/65760/48355