# Add a custom field's in registration form with relationship

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute, dropdown-attribute

I need a little help ..

I need to create a new field in the registration form, and this field needs to be dynamic.

I enter the panel and add the options that I want to appear in this form, and in the registration page the user chooses one of this information.

I need 2 tables to make this query, just by business rule.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/65760/48355), then you replace the install script with this one:

```
<?php
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'license_number', array(
    'type'      => 'int',
    'label'     => 'License Number',
    'input'     => 'select',
    'position'  => 120,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
    'source'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table', 
    'option'    => [
        'values'=> [
             0 => 'Information 1',
             1 => 'Information 2',
             2 => 'Information 3',
        ]
    ],
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'license_number');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
```

Nb: The attribute wil be stored in **eav_attribute** table.

Comment: can how i create a table with that?

Comment: I need to create 2 tables, like a hive of activity, and hive of activity erp.. But i don't know how to start..

Comment: the solution that i gave you adds the field and attribute in `eav_attribute` table