# Custom customer attribute for Magento CE

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9 CE, so "manage customer attributes" is not a default feature, but I want to add a simple yes/no customer attribute that could be set from admin panel.

I cannot seem to find any decent tutorials for Magento 1.X...

If anyone could guide me through this or link a tutorial it'd be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via an upgrade script and not via admin.

**app/code/local/your namespace/your module/sql/modulename_customer_setup/install-1.0.0.php**

```
<?php
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'yourattribute_name', array(
    'type'      => 'int',
    'label'     => 'Yourattribute Name',
    'input'     => 'select',
    'position'  => 120,
    'default' => array(0),
    'source'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'yourattribute_name');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
```

For more informations [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/65760/48355).

Comment: Thank you! For whatever reason did not stumble upon that answer myself

Comment: Sorry, do you know if there is a way of saving these values not as `1` and `0` but `yes` and `no`?

Comment: add this : `'option'        => array(
                'value' => array(
                                '0' => 'no',
                                '1' => 'yes'
                            )), `