# How can I add some extra labels for the address in the adminpanel in M1?

Tags: magento-1, customer-address, labels

I would like to add some extra labels to html code from the address , like in the image:
[image]

Right after the `street address` I would like to add some labels. Right now I added via jQuery, but I have to change a lot , when there is an address when you want to add a new address etc .

I know that this class method: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Addresses::initForm` is responsible for getting displayed those inputs. And in the `customer/tab/addresses.phtml` there is a big js, which is also responsabile for it. The fact is that everyhing that I change is a dead end. Is it possible to add those labels ? maybe If I rewrite the block and change smth in it . Any idea how can I do that ?

Comment: [Check this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/65760/20064) it may be helpful

Comment: @Piyush That is different, it adds a new attribute. I don't need that . I need to edit the existing default one : address, which is divide in 4 parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I still end up using jQuery for the customer address and for the sales order address I used prototype.
First I rewrite the data.phtml . here is the xml code:

```
   <adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
       <reference name="data">
           <action method="setTemplate"><file>mynamespace_mymodule/sales/order/create/data.phtml</file></action>
       </reference>
   </adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data> 

   <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <reference name="data">
            <action method="setTemplate"><file>mynamespace_mymodule/sales/order/create/data.phtml</file></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
```

and in the end of the  file I added this js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // adding additional labels in the sales order new or sales order edit page
    var elements = ['[for="order-billing_address_street0"]', '[for="order-shipping_address_street0"]', '[for="_item1street0"]', '[for="_item2street0"]', '[for="_item3street0"]'];
    htmlLabels = '<label for="streetlabel1"><?php echo Mage::helper('mynamespace_mymodule')->__('Housenumber') ?></label><label for="streetlabel2"><?php echo Mage::helper('mynamespace_mymodule')->__('Housenumber addition') ?></label><label for="streetlabel3"><?php echo Mage::helper('mynamespace_mymodule')->__('Appt') ?></label>';
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var elementAfter = document.querySelector(elements[i]);
        if (elementAfter != null) {
            //insert html content after element X
            elementAfter.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', htmlLabels);
        }
    }
</script>
```

The js script is only made for the sales orders create address. I'm not happy with it, but it s working.