# create 3 web-forms for each group registration containing custom fields

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I want to create 3 custom forms for the registration.

I have find `/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/`
 - `register.phtml`
 - `login.phtml`

the groups i want to have custom forms is: company in EU, General, company outside EU

I have 3 select on the registration page.
But i don´t now how to create the forms so i can sign them to the right group.

Hope someone can help me.

**uppdate:**

I follow this tutorial, but all i see is a blank page.
https://midpart.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/a-new-registration-form-for-wholesale-customer/

I use Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: It'll help you, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/65760/48355

Comment: I wery new in magento, specific programing.
Can see what i´m doing wrong.

Comment: if you don't post what you did, I can't or we can't see and help you

Comment: Hello, I manage to fix it my self...thanks for the help