# Magento 1.9 database insert file

Tags: magento-1.9, database, create-account

I try to add a **new field** to the **customer form** , on the **create account** page.

What I don't understand is where can I find the file which holds the **script** with the **database insert values**. Like the **"model"** file from the **MVC** systems.

Comment: Please review this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration

Comment: @ShorabhKumarGupta, it's what I need, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find all core module of the customer in following folder :

App->code->core ->Mage->Customer