# Magento 1.9 Add an optional customer attribute on registration form only for my Brasilian shop?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, register

I want to show a customer attribute on registration form and provide to edit that one on user profile, but only for my Brasilian customers?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create customer attribute for this you can do follow:

1. Go to admin and open Customers->Attributes->Manage Attribute.
2. Select Store on which you want to enable that attribute **ex: Brasilian Store**
3. Fill out all the necessary filed according to your need then save it.
4. Run indexing and flush cache.
5. For showing your customer attribute on registration page go to its Phtml file and call that attribute by its Code which you gave to your attribute while creating it.
   Like:

   escapeHtml($this->getCustomer()->getProvince()) ?>

let me know if its work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no Customers->Attributes->Manage Attribute.

Comment: @BorcheGlafche Welcome Pal let me know if above solution work or not.

Comment: It doesn't. There is no Customers->Attributes->Manage Attribute on admin page.

Comment: Can You share screenshot of your backend so that we can figure it out.

Comment: You can refer this link also [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration]

Comment: I uploaded a  screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83264/discussion-between-borche-glafche-and-shubham-khandelwal).

Answer (score 0):

1. You create a customer attribute
2. ```
   app/design/frontend/{template}/{name}/template/customer/form/register.phtml

   app/design/frontend/{template}/{name}/template/customer/form.phtml
   ```

   You add a condition around your field:

   ```
   <?php $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(); ?>
   <?php if ($storeCode == 'br') : ?>
       //your Brasilian input here
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```