# When implementing an SQL upgrade script, do I need an install script for stores that have never had a previous version of the module?

Tags: module, magento-1, install-script, upgrade-script

I understand how to execute an install or upgrade script with my Magento module. My question is, when someone installs the latest version of a module and has never had a previous version installed, does Magento cycle through the previous version installs until the final upgrade script is ran or, in addition to each versions upgrade script, do I need an install file?

Comment: take a look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/26314/146. Maybe it helps a little.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you follow the right naming convention, example:

- `install-0.1.0.php`
- `upgrade-0.1.0-0.2.0.php`
- `upgrade-0.2.0-1.0.0.php`

Magento will first check if the module is installed.

If it's not installed, it will start with the install script then go through every upgrade script.

In case it's already installed, it will first check the version installed via the `core_resource` table then call the missing upgrade scripts.

Comment: Bonus points for not including the antiquated `mysql4-` prefix!